# quilljs allow user to pick color like input

Tags: javascript, quill

So I know you can add color options to the color field, e.g.

```
[{'color': "#000000"}]
```

But I was wondering if there was a way to make it so that the user can choose the colors like in a

```
<input type="color">
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use custom toolbar [handler](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/#handlers) and with a bit of javascript you can work your way out.

Take a look at the code snippet below, which basically adds a hidden color input to the dom and then uses it to open color picker dialog. You can modify it to look more elegant, code below is just for your reference.

```js
var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      [{
        header: [1, 2, false]
      }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['image', 'code-block'],
      [{
        'color': ['#F00', '#0F0', '#00F', '#000', '#FFF', 'color-picker']
      }]
    ]
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
  theme: 'snow' // or 'bubble'
});

function showColorPicker(value) {
  if (value === 'color-picker') {
    var picker = document.getElementById('color-picker');
    if (!picker) {
      picker = document.createElement('input');
      picker.id = 'color-picker';
      picker.type = 'color';
      picker.style.display = 'none';
      picker.value = '#FF0000';
      document.body.appendChild(picker);

      picker.addEventListener('change', function() {
        quill.format('color', picker.value);
      }, false);
    }
    picker.click();
  } else {
    quill.format('color', value);
  }
}

var toolbar = quill.getModule('toolbar');
toolbar.addHandler('color', showColorPicker);
```

```css
#editor-container {
  height: 375px;
}

.ql-color .ql-picker-options [data-value=color-picker]:before {
  content: 'Pick Color';
}

.ql-color .ql-picker-options [data-value=color-picker] {
  background: none !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 25px !important;
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.bubble.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.7.1/katex.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/styles/monokai-sublime.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="editor-container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you mean colorpicker to the toolbar?

```
toolbar: [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }]
```

Comment: yes, but the actual colour selection thing you get from using `<input type="color"` so the user can select any colour they want, rather than a preset number

Answer (score 0):

To add custom color in ngx-quill we can use select with option color:

```
<select class="ql-color">
                    <option value="#048543"></option>
                    <option value="#f6a11d"></option>
                    <option value="#a3a3a3"></option>
                    <option value="#fff"></option>
                </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

okay after a bit of research I found that using the input type color for quill bg and text color is pretty straight forward.
you have to give the input an identifier and an event listener and then feed quill with the data when changed. example;

```js
var quill = new Quill("#editor", {
        modules: {
          toolbar: {
            container: "#toolbar",
          },
        },
      });
      
      //IMPORTANT PART
        let quillColor = document.querySelector("#quillColor");
      quillColor.onchange = function () {
        let color = quillColor.value;
        quill.format("color", color);
      };
```

```html
<input type="color" id="quillColor" />
```